# current webrtc ios static library - e.g. libwebrtc_arm64.a?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, p2p, rtcdatachannel

I've used the [WebRTC DataConnection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel) in browsers a lot for p2p communication. Now I'd like to do the same within an iOS app.

I live and develop in a remote region with very slow Internet access. So [building the webrtc source](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/) myself which involves a 6+ GB download to generate the static library is very difficult. I attempted from a different location and because of the complexity of the build process failed and ran out of time to debug.

I found the [libjingle_peerconnection cocoa pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/libjingle_peerconnection), but the static library this provides is over 70MB which seems too large for an iOS app. I'm wondering if it includes libjingle and webrtc video (I just want to use RTCDataChannels) code that isn't necessary?

I just need a prebuilt iOS arm64 library

Comment: I'd think that if you were to check out the source, then deltas across a slow connection would typically be a lot less painful.   Back when bandwidth was measured by how fast you could toss potatoes, we'd send out snapshots via fedex'd hard drives, and then use UUCP to copy the diffs across the unbelievably slow connections.  Worked well enough.  A modern revision control should do compression on the wire and the delta downloads are fairly compact (as long as there aren't a lot of binaries). Assumes the code is in a repository somewhere.

Comment: The problem is checking out the source - it apparently checks out all of chromium and the tools used are unfamiliar to me at least - depot tools, gclient sync. It's not like we are dealing with git or svn here

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for my needs which is to use an entirely different iOS WebRTC implementation:

[OpenWebRTC](http://www.openwebrtc.org/) which has a great [iOS SDK](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-ios-sdk), [examples](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples), and [pre-built binaries](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc/releases)!